# Sendgrid Introduction Throws Forbidden Error

Tags: python, sendgrid

I'm running through Sendgrid's [intro material for Python](https://app.sendgrid.com/guide/integrate/langs/python) but executing the example code throws a 403-Forbidden error.

Steps I took:

1. Create API Key & `sendgrid.env` file as instructed.
2. Create a conda environment with python 3.5: `conda create -n sendgrid python=3.5`
3. Install sendgrid: `(sendgrid) pip install sendgrid`
4. Run example: `(sendgrid) python main.py`

Where `main.py` contains the exact code copied from the example page linked above.

**Issue:** Running `main.py` throws the error `HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`.

Things I've tried:

- I tried switching out the to and from emails in that example, but doesn't change the result.
- I also tried the same flow but using NodeJS but same result.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Give API Key its full access, follow steps:

1. Settings
2. API Keys
3. Edit API Key
4. Full Access
5. Update

---

Whitelist your domain, follow steps:

1. Settings
2. Sender Authentication
3. Domain Authentication
4. Select DNS Host
5. Enter your domain name
6. Copy all records and put them in your Advanced DNS management console

NOTE: When adding records, make sure not to have domain name in the host. Crop it out.

If you do not want to authenticate domain, you can try with **Single Sender Verification** as well.

Note: It might take some time for records to start functioning.

---

If you're using pylinter, `e.message` will say

```
Instance of 'Exception' has no 'message' member
```

This is because `message` attribute is generated dynamically by `sendgrid` which pylinter is unable to access as it doesn't exists before runtime.

So, to prevent that, at the top of your file or above `print(e.message)` line, you need to add either one of the below, they mean the same thing-

```
# pylint: disable=no-member
```

E1101 is code to `no-member`, fine more [here](https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/features.html#id6)

```
# pylint: disable=E1101
```

---

Now the code below should work for you. Just make sure you have `SENDGRID_API_KEY` set in environment. If not, you may also directly replace it with `os.environ.get("SENDGRID_API_KEY")` which is not a good practice though.

```
# pylint: disable=E1101

import os
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail

message = Mail(
    from_email="from_email@your-whitelisted-domain.com",
    to_emails=("recipient1@example.com", "recipient2@example.com"),
    subject="Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun",
    html_content="<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Python</strong>")
try:
    sg = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get("SENDGRID_API_KEY"))
    response = sg.send(message)
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.body)
    print(response.headers)
except Exception as e:
    print(e.message)
```